# Read web.config from browser-enabled InfoPath form

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, web-config

I've built in C# a dll that accesses the appSettings section from the web.config file in the Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80. I do it the way it was described by Microsoft Community [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555963). I use this dll in a browser-enabled form published to a SharePoint site collection. 
It works fine on my local machine, but when i publish it to the server, it cannot access the configuration file. What could be the reason?

Comment: Have you updated the Config file in the Machine that you have deployed the Form ? What is the error you are getting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what was wrong. I've checked the path of the config file the application was using. I don't know why, but it was using the web.config from a web application on another port (8080 instead of 80).

I've added the configuration data to that config file and now it works fine.